# How to solve this type of equation with posynomial form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I have an equation with the following form where the goal is to find $x$:
$$ \sum_k c_k x^{\gamma_k} = 1$$
where $c_k, \gamma_k \in \Re^+$ and $\gamma_k > 1$
Alternatively using $y = \log(x)$ I can write this as:
$$ \sum_k c_k e^{\gamma_k \; y} = 1$$. Now the lhs is convex in $y$.
Since for $y = -\infty $ the lhs is equal to zero and for $y = +\infty$ it is infinity it should have a single solution in between right?

How can I  analytically solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: I see no reason to believe it would have an analytic solution.